# javascript validation with email check

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

when email are already existed, validation is hit the form action redirect the

page.i wanted to if email and all field are right way then hit the action part.

ajax success function not to return properly.

```
<script language="javascript">
    function validate()
    {    
        var str = true;
        document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("msg5").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("msg6").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("msg7").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("msg8").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("msg9").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("msg10").innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("msg11").innerHTML = "";

        if (!document.frm.firstname.value == '')
        {
            var patterns = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;

            if (!document.frm.firstname.value.match(patterns))
            {
                document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = "Please Enter only letters";
                str = false;
            }

        } else
        {
            document.getElementById("msg1").innerHTML = "Please Enter First Name";

            str = false;
        }

        if (!document.frm.lastname.value == '')
        {
            var patterns = /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/;

            if (!document.frm.lastname.value.match(patterns))
            {
                document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = "Please Enter only letters";
                str = false;
            }

        } else
        {
            document.getElementById("msg2").innerHTML = "Please Enter Last Name";
            str = false;
        }

        if (document.frm.password.value == '')
        {
            document.getElementById("msg4").innerHTML = "Please Enter Password";
            str = false;
        }

        var phoneno = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;

        if (!document.frm.phone.value.match(phoneno))
        {
            document.getElementById("msg5").innerHTML = "Please Enter 10 Digits Mobiles";
            str = false;
        }

        if (document.frm.country.value == '')
        {
            document.getElementById("msg6").innerHTML = "Please Enter Country";
            str = false;
        }

        if (document.frm.state.value == '')
        {
            document.getElementById("msg7").innerHTML = "Please Enter State";
            str = false;
        }

        if (document.frm.city.value == '')
        {
            document.getElementById("msg8").innerHTML = "Please Enter City";
            str = false;
        }

        if (document.frm.address.value == '')
        {
            document.getElementById("msg9").innerHTML = "Please Enter Address";
            str = false;
        }

        if (document.frm.industry.value == '')
        {
            document.getElementById("msg10").innerHTML = "Please Select Industry";
            str = false;
        }

        if (document.frm.company.value == '')
        {
            document.getElementById("msg11").innerHTML = "Please Enter Company Name";
            str = false;
        }

        if (!document.frm.email.value == '')
        {
            var validate_char = /^([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z])+\.+?(com|co|in|org|net|edu|info|gov|vekomy))\.?(com|co|in|org|net|edu|info|gov)?$/;

            if (!document.frm.email.value.match(validate_char))
            {
                document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";
                str = false;
            } else {
                var Email = document.frm.email.value;
                var datastring = 'Email=' + Email;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "client_email.php",
                    data: datastring,
                    success: function(responseText) {
                        if (responseText == 1)
                        {
                            $("#msg3").html("Email Is Already Exists");
                            str = false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else
        {
            document.getElementById("msg3").innerHTML = "Email Field Is Empty";
            str = false;
        }

        return str;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: ajax is async. Your code will continue to execute without waiting for the ajax response.

Comment: Is there  a reason you only allow email addresses that uses those specific tld's, and not all available tld's?

Comment: @tarangp - When you reformatted the OP's code, you changed the OP's original regex-pattern for the email check. Never format regexes! Adding arbitrary spaces in a regex pattern _changes_ the pattern. Every character (including white spaces) matters.

Comment: why is not work 'str = false;' in success function.

Answer (score 0):

Use HTML5's new type attributes to accomplish this..
For email validity write:
    `<input type="email" name="email" required/>`
and if the email is empty or wrong manner ,it will never hit submit event..Hence will not be redirected...
For eg:https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FNZQV8G6AJ8P

for more types:https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

Server Side:
[Form Required Every Field By PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_required.asp)

[Form Type Validation By PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_form_url_email.asp)

Comment: but adding novalidate attribute will remove all validation from client browser so client side is an optional thing please validate the form from server side

Comment: Plus, adding `required` doesn't really help the OP with checking if the email already exists in the DB.

Comment: W3Schools, as a reference, is often incomplete or inaccurate. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#Form_%3Cinput%3E_types) is generally more reliable.

Comment: The example that is given in there is perfect for demonstration and practice purposes..

Comment: The [example](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FNZQV8G6AJ8P), yes. The [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) you linked is missing the `file`, `hidden`, and `image` input types.